# Vectorization of FOR loop

Tags: vectorization, octave

Is there a way to vectorize this FOR loop I know about *gallery ("circul",y)* thanks to user carandraug
but this will only shift the cell over to the next adjacent cell I also tried toeplitz but that didn't work).

**I'm trying to make the shift adjustable which is done in the example code with circshift and the variable shift_over.**

The variable **y_new** is the output I'm trying to get but without having to use a FOR loop in the example (can this FOR loop be vectorized).

**Please note:** The numbers that are used in this example are just an example the real array will be voice/audio 30-60 second signals (so the y_new array could be large) and won't be sequential numbers like 1,2,3,4,5.

```
tic
y=[1:5];
[rw col]= size(y); %get size to create zero'd array
y_new= zeros(max(rw,col),max(rw,col)); %zero fill new array for speed

shift_over=-2; %cell amount to shift over

for aa=1:length(y)
  if aa==1
    y_new(aa,:)=y; %starts with original array
  else  
    y_new(aa,:)=circshift(y,[1,(aa-1)*shift_over]); %
  endif
end
y_new

fprintf('\nfinally Done-elapsed time -%4.4fsec- or -%4.4fmins- or -%4.4fhours-\n',toc,toc/60,toc/3600);


y_new =

           1           2           3           4           5
           3           4           5           1           2
           5           1           2           3           4
           2           3           4           5           1
           4           5           1           2           3
```

Ps:  I'm using Octave 4.2.2 Ubuntu 18.04 64bit.

Comment: It's always hard to figure out what you are actually trying to do. I have to read the question again and again and then analyse the existing snippet. I think you questions would get more attention is it would be easier to find out what you want to do in the first place. Btw, have you read http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Comment: @Andy I'm sorry I really do try and explain it fully I include example of the code. Along with the output `y_new` I'm trying to get, along with a note what I'm trying to do.  `Please note: The numbers that are used in this example are just an example the real array will be voice/audio 30-60 second signals (so the y_new array could be large) and won't be sequential numbers like 1,2,3,4,5`. (maybe I'm including to much info) I'm not sure how I can say How can I vectorize a FOR loop more directly. I did included that in the first line and the title.

Comment: I guess you haven't read about the XY problem yet, right?

Comment: @RickT I think the question is, why do you need `y_new`? What are you going to be doing with it after you generate it? Is it possible to process your data without creating a possibly huge matrix of signals?

Comment: @Andy yes I did read it and I really do see your point, the thing is I'm experimenting with audio signals in a multitude of ways.   When one experiment doesn't work I re-work the theory and try something different.

Comment: @beaker I fully see Andy's and your point.  The thing is I'm experimenting with audio signals in a multitude of ways. When one experiment doesn't work I re-work the theory and try something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a classic XY problem where you want to calculate something and you think it's a good idea to build a redundant n x n matrix where n is the length of your audio file in samples. Perhaps you want to play with autocorrelation **but the key point here is that I doubt that building the requested matrix is a good idea** but here you go:

Your code:

```
y = rand (1, 3e3);
shift_over = -2;

clear -x y shift_over
tic
[rw col]= size(y); %get size to create zero'd array
y_new= zeros(max(rw,col),max(rw,col)); %zero fill new array for speed

for aa=1:length(y)
  if aa==1
    y_new(aa,:)=y; %starts with original array
  else  
    y_new(aa,:)=circshift(y,[1,(aa-1)*shift_over]); %
  endif
end
toc
```

my code:

```
clear -x y shift_over
tic
n = numel (y);
y2 = y (mod ((0:n-1) - shift_over * (0:n-1).', n) + 1);
toc
```

gives on my system:

```
Elapsed time is 1.00379 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.155854 seconds.
```